# Domain Driven Design: Using the Domain in the Blazor UI

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

We are creating a application in C# with Blazor and Azure Functions.

Assume we have the following code

```
var trade = //create some trade

trade.AddItems(...)

trade.Save();
```

When items are added fees automatically gets calculated and recorded on the trade.

We want to be able to show the fees on the fly as items gets added on the UI. Would it be against the DDD ethos to use the Domain code above in the ui as well to display the Fees.

Going further lets say one were allowed to save the trade and return to the UI page later, would it be against the DDD ethos to return the aggregate root, Trade, to the ui.

Doing both of these seems like a very simple approach, but what would be recommended way of doing this with the same sort of efficiency?

Answer (score 2):

I think that your use of the domain model in different situations demonstrates the power of DDD.

Specifically, the domain model can implement logic without a care about the infrastructure it is being executed in.

I have a similar situation where I'm using my domain model in a Blazor client (with network disconnection resilience), but also in the bounded context behind an API on the server, where the records are finally persisted.

In the client, I use IndexedDb for storage of the model, but on the server I'm using SQL Server (via Entity Framework) to persist the same model.  Similarly, my command pipeline on the client is different to that behind the API.

The model does not care that I'm using a different infrastructure around it and this is one of the strengths of DDD.

Regarding returning the aggregate root to the UI, as the aggregate root is initially materialised behind an API, but is then serialized / deserialized on way back to client, we are not dealing with the same 'object'.

We may use the same classes populated with the same data to get real-time business logic results on the client, but any updates to the original 'object' would still require a new request via your API.

As a final note, if your domain model cannot be used in both contexts at the same time, it is probably telling you that you've got your DDD wrong.